# Android GCM "error":"NotRegistered"

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I am using Android GCM Push service, it works great for some time, but if I keep my application Idle for some minutes, or when i rerun it after some modifications in the code i get no messages and the GCM server give me this error :"NotRegistered" i did some resurch i found [this posted question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12919668/google-android-gcm-notregistered-error) but i cant comment there yet (low reputation :( and the post is so old)

While going through it i undrestand that sometime Google server can refresh registration id automatically, So what i need to know is when exactly the GCM server dose these modifications on the regestration id and how to update my saved regID in my database

I'm new so hope that my question is clear
Thank you for helping me out

Comment: You should check your logcat to see if you receive a com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION intent with unregistered value before you start getting the NotRegistered error at your server. That would mean that GCM unregistered the device for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

If you change some of your codes, and reinstall the app on your device, the last token may changed. Google **may** update the token on these cases:

- App update
- Re installation
- Clearing the app data

Then you should handle the `onTokenRefresh` your self to save the token and update it in your server database.