# Google Cloud Messaging iOS 'NotRegistered' for some iOS devices

Tags: google-cloud-messaging

I use GCM in combination with an iOS app. The app registeres the device with GCM. I get a token from GCM, but when I send a message GCM reports ' NotRegistered'. Ik have tried to reinstall the app from Xcode, but the token is the same and keeps saying 'NotRegistered'. Deleting the app en reinstalling is does not help.

I have this problem on multiple devices (iPhone 6 iOS 9.1), iPad 3 and iPhone 4s. I have it working on a different iPhone 6 and iPhone 5s.

Could someone tell what is wrong? Or maybe how to force a new token from GCM?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You will get a new a registration token every time you reinstall your application. You can read the [GCM key concept documentation](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/gcm#key) for more details. Your problem should be in your HTTP request, potentially wrong senderID or API Key. Also, you should try the get a reg token by using [this sample demo](https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/tree/master/ios/gcm)

Comment: Could you include the code you are using to generate the token and also the code used to send the message to the device.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android GCM "error":"NotRegistered"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23470252/android-gcm-errornotregistered)