# GCM returning notRegisteded

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

Here is my Java code.

```
@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    // Make a call to Instance API
    InstanceID instanceID = InstanceID.getInstance(this);
    String senderId = getResources().getString(R.string.gcm_defaultSenderId);
    try {
        // request token that will be used by the server to send push notifications
        String token = instanceID.getToken(senderId, GoogleCloudMessaging.INSTANCE_ID_SCOPE,null);
        Log.d(TAG, "GCM Registration Token: " + token);

        // pass along this data
        sendRegistrationToServer(token);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I copied the registration id, and used postman to push notifications to android device, it is giving error: notRegistered.

Here is my postman request

URL:  https://gcm-http.googleapis.com/gcm/send

```
 {
  "to": "<registration_Key>",
  "data": {
    "message": "This is a GCM Topic Message!"
   }
 }
```

I tried copying the key, I tried creating a rest endpoint in nodejs which will receive this key and execute gcm request, but in both cases it is returning following response.

```
{
    "multicast_id": 7402052379497307216,
    "success": 0,
    "failure": 1,
    "canonical_ids": 0,
    "results": [
      {
         "error": "NotRegistered"
      }
    ]
 }
```

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23470252/android-gcm-errornotregistered

Comment: @abielita, I found the issue but not solution, It is generating different token when I use register() which is deprecated. This token works perfect. But if I use getToken(), it doesnt work.